# Limit Form Submission Only to Mobile App

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

We are providing a form inside an iOS app for users to be able to fill out a survey. The submission works against our rails server, however, we don't require any user authentication since it's a public facing app. My concern is that with a properly configured curl command, someone could easily write a script that could fill up the database very quickly with bogus data. I could probably add some rate limiting that might help, but what would be a good way to minimally prevent someone from doing this? You could maybe limit it by using some obscure user agent that couldn't easily be guessed, but is there some sort of token scheme or some similar that would work that wouldn't require us to implement user auth? I'm not looking for absolute security--just a basic deterrent. Any ideas? Thanks.